# Using an object reference to set initial state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While trying to follow the DRY principle I began wondering if the following be encouraged/discouraged in react projects:

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  foo: foobar,
  bar: barfoo
}

class Tuna extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = DEFAULT_STATE
  }
  ...
  reset = () => {
    this.setState(DEFAULT_STATE)
  }
  ...
}
```

or would this be any better (assuming that there are no objects nested inside DEFAULT_STATE)

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  foo: foobar,
  bar: barfoo
}

class Tuna extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {...DEFAULT_STATE}
  }
  ...
  reset = () => {
    this.setState({...DEFAULT_STATE})
  }
  ...
}
```

or just plain old this (repeating code)

```
class Tuna extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      foo: foobar,
      bar: barfoo
    }
  }
  ...
  reset = () => {
    this.setState({
      foo: foobar,
      bar: barfoo
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

thank you.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the first approach. The second approach is an unnecessary use of the spread syntax in my opinion. The last approach has duplicate code which would be discouraged in general.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, you will have no problems if you do not change the initial object. But if you change object may experience the following problems, for example:

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  foo: foobar,
  bar: barfoo
}
    class Tuna extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = DEFAULT_STATE
      }
      ...
      reset = () => {
        this.setState(DEFAULT_STATE)
      }
      someFunc = () => {
        this.state.foo.push({field: 'lol'})
      }

      someFuncAfterReset = () => {
        console.log(this.state.foo) // always [{field: 'lol'}]
      }
    }
```

Except the third case

Comment: This is wrong. Firstly `this.state.foo.push({field: 'lol'})` is invalid for React and will not work correctly because of that. It will not output `[{field: 'lol'}]` and instead output `[foobar, {field: 'lol'}]`. Because the state was modified directly which is something that is never supposed to be done the object will never go away and instead will be getting appended every time you call `someFunc`. The correct way to do this is `this.setState({"foo": <value>});` which will have no issues with going back to the default value when `reset` is called.

Comment: I agree completely. This is wrong. My answer is about a typical beginner's mistake. As I said except the third case.